# $results gets multiple results back, but only last one gets updated on mysql_query. Would need all updated

Tags: php, mysql

I know this should be kind of simple, but I just can't figure it out on my own. So heres the code:

```
while($row01=mysql_fetch_array($res01))
{
    $results=stripslashes($row01['spec_search'])." ";
    echo $results;
    mysql_query("update products set search='".$results."' WHERE id='".$row['id']."' ");
}
```

The *$results* return multiple values. It echoes well, like "tree bag shoes". But at the *mysql_query* only the last result (shoes in this example) gets updated in my table. How can I make it so that everything gets updated?

Many thanks!

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't be using the MySQL library, MySQLi should be used. Secondly, you haven't got it to display any errors, add `or die(mysql_error())` to the end of `mysql_query()` to see if there any any issues.

Comment: $result and $row seem to appear out of nowhere... I suppose you meant to use $results and $row01 ?

Comment: There are no errors shown, as Kami pointed out:"The database is not updating once, but multiple times. However as the updates are being applied to the same row, only the last update is visible."

$result was a typo on my part, it is $results. fixed that.

$row is defined already (not shown here) and that works fine, it shouldn't be an issue. It has been tested on its own.

$specArr is just leftover code. I forgot to remove that from here. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$row['id']` in the query, but the loop's current row is accessed by `$row01['id']`.

The database is not updating once, but multiple times. However as the updates are being applied to the same row, only the last update is visible.

Update you code to the following

```
while($row01=mysql_fetch_array($res01))
{
    $results=stripslashes($row01['spec_search'])." ";
    $specArr[$row['id']][]=$row01['id'];
    echo $results;
    mysql_query("update products set search='".$results."' WHERE id='".$row01['id']."' ");
}
```

Comment: $row is defined elsewhere, but that works good as it points to the correct row in 'products' table. That has been tested

Comment: As you've pointed out correctly the problem is that the table gets updated multiple times. How can I get around that?

Comment: @crashtest see the code sample.  Change `$row['id']` in the query to `$row01['id']`.  That should use the index from currently looped item.

Comment: $row01 comes from a different table where I get the spec_search from, but the to be updated table is where $row is defined, so that is defined correctly. So that part is good as it is. The problem is exactly what you described with the multiple updates.

Comment: @crashtest The multiple updates to the same row are happening because `$row['id']` is the same in this loop.  From you sample I thought you needed to use `$row01['id']`. If that is not the case then change the `WHERE id='"` section to use the correct set of `id` values.

Comment: The id value needs to be the same, because the values I need from $results should all go to the same row with the same id... I feel a bit stranded.
I am thinking of an array where all the info gathered by $results is collected and then add that whole array to my mysql_query. I just couldn't get that working either...

Answer (score 0):

I've found the right way to get the data into an array and then get it back. Here it is:

```
$results = array(); //make an array
while($row01=mysql_fetch_assoc($res01)) //assoc is needed, not ok with array!
{
    $res=stripslashes($row01['spec_search'])." ";
    $results[] = $res; //load up in array
    mysql_query("update products set search='".implode('', $results)."' WHERE id='".$row['id']."' ");
}
        echo implode('', $results); //this is how get data back from array
```